# Near-Death Experiences At a Point in History with No Medical Science?

Tags: survival, history, death

I want a scenario where a person witnesses a "near death experience". But here's the catch -- there is no medical science available (pick your time, as far back as you like). The person must somehow be brought to the brink of death, and then brought back, without fancy technology. How can I do this?

I'm imagining how this might happen without medical science. That is, no technology to "force" a person back to life - just something coincidental or naturally occurring, or possibly a way for a human to go through a near-death experience but return from it with no particular effort. This could include, I guess, a freak lightning strike, or the grieving partner thumping the dying person on the chest at just the right moment, shouting "don't you dare leave me!" or whatever. I'd like to stay away from anything that could be recognised as rudimentary modern medicine, but we might be able to go as far as the local Elder rushing over with the "magical herbs" or something.

I'm imagining the person who experiences dear-death would return to their village or people and tell them of what they've seen, and this perhaps being a pillar for the subsequent formation of religion or belief in something bigger than themselves. As such, it would help if it could be confirmed by more than one person in relatively short order (eg. Grandma saying "Yeah, I seem to remember Old George from over the hill talking about that once"). As likely little would be written, it would need to survive some oral telling. Relatively regular confirmation might be necessary to keep it "current" until subsequently someone "joins the dots" and uses it as the basis of a belief system.

I'm thinking of the often cited experience of seeing a bright light down a tunnel or corridor and being drawn to it. Perhaps also looking down on one's own dead/dying body, but feeling a calmness with no discomfort or difficulty in that, before suddenly being pulled back into living reality. As far as I know, most accounts along these lines tend to centre around a hospital experience, perhaps being given CPR or a defibrillator shock or whatever to bring someone back to life, the person suddenly becoming aware of the doctors all working, the machines beeping, spouse crying, beloved dog barking, etc.

Edit after comments:
I'm definitely NOT trying to define what someone may or may not experience, or indeed their exact clinical status of "alive or dead". The point here is that they would be believed to be dead by others, and without some sort of intervention they would die, but something happens to pull them back to life, after which they can tell the tale of what they saw (or thought they saw).

I'm simply after possible circumstances in which someone that was formerly on a trajectory towards permanent death is diverted from it back to life again. As I say, without any specific medical science or even intentional action.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no worldbuilding question here. Can you cite proof that CPR, defibrillation, or any other medical practice is the *one and only way* that a Near Death Experience can be had? How is this not storytelling? What rule of your world (something that's independent of all stories) are you asking about? Why won't any of the answers you provide (that's prohibited, BTW, see [help/dont-ask]) work?

Comment: Also, please note that I think your perspective about near death experiences is heavily tainted by the fact that 99% of the documentation about them is from the 20th century. Before having the ability to identify the experience as "they were near death," which could only be done medically, what you had was someone that had a vision and since they lived, no one thought to ask, "hey, did you almost die or what?" I believe you're hung up on how we explain this today because you haven't thought through how it would be explained historically without the benefit of today's medical science.

Comment: Ah, at first I thought you were asking "*what* might the person experience" (in which case there's a deep rabbit hole [here](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc461731/)) but now I see you mean "*how* might they experience near-death (without dying, without modern medical techniques)." I believe JBH had the same moment of confusion as I did. You could probably get a lot of mileage out of stories where someone actually woke up during the "wake" (or were accidentally buried alive). Modern technology brings more people back but also finds more of them that weren't really dead...

Comment: I've read and re-read my question, and I'm struggling to see how to see how I suggested I was looking to confirm or debunk modern experiences or the circumstances leading to them. I've had a crack at clarifying, but happy to be lead further to improve the question.

Comment: Hey Ralph. I have edited the question to make it more obvious from the very start what you are asking. Rephrased the first paragraph and moved the confusing second paragraph further down. Feel free to reverse any of my edits if I got the wrong idea.

Answer (score 8):

I think it can happen when the subject falls into water close to the freezing point, resulting in the subject losing consciousness following cardiac arrest.

Reanimation might be possible with simple methods (northern fishermen fallen in the sea were put in bed with their wives to be slowly warmed up), and it's likely that the experience might results in what you ask.

There is even a [documented case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_B%C3%A5genholm) where the subject recovered after showing no life signs (even though she was treated with modern medicine techniques)

Comment: I like the sound of this - the doting partner pulls the victim from the icy water, lays them out on the shore, and "hugs them one last time" (perhaps at their camp, where they have a fire and a blanket or whatever), and they are revived to tell the tale of what they just experienced...

Answer (score 7):

Near-death experiences were recounted by ancient Greek philosophers.  Plato told the story of Er in the *Republic*:  he had been "killed" on the battlefield and regained consciousness on his funeral pyre.  ( Heraclitus and Democritus also theorized about them, but they do not appear to have recounted a tale.)

Consequently, you may just want a man suffering wounds on the battlefield to make an inexplicable recovery.

Comment: I'm after the means it could happen, which @Nepene Nep suggests could be by someone "patching up" the injured to stop further blood loss, etc. Then some gradual (unconscious) recovery, followed by perhaps an additional sense of urgency caused by the flames of the funeral pyre. That certainly seems imaginable!

Answer (score 2):

See Chapter 12: Near-Death Experiences". In Cardeña, Etzel; Lynn, Steven Jay; Krippner, Stanley (eds.). Varieties of anomalous experience : examining the scientific evidence from 1892.

Falling, soldiers who have injuries from war, accidents, and near drownings were the common sorts of experiences that led to near death experiences. What you need is someone to be close to death from bloodloss but to be patched up, or someone to almost die from drowning but get to air in time. Those in the past understood the basics of warming people up and stopping bleeding out, and someone could easily have a near death experience from that.

Comment: These make a lot of sense to me - and you could easily imagine a friend or someone tying up a leg or something in the hope the injured may survive. Loss of blood could conceivably "amplify" the brain into thinking it was dying etc.

Comment: Yeah. And there are a lot of situations that could result in it. Accident with farming, war, a mine collapsing, whatever works for your story.

Answer (score 1):

### In many cases of near death experience, recovery is spontaneous

A head injury or certain infections can cause swelling of the brain resulting in a coma.  You could appear dead for days and experience an extended lucid dream state before the swelling subsides returning you to normal functions

Any other injury can also put you into a state of shock which can naturally last up to a few hours before your body naturally returns to normal function on its own.  Sometimes these injuries don't even need to be major.  I've seen a person report an out of body experience and bright light just before passing out from a small cut on thier finger tip before... shock is the result of believing you've been critically wounded much more than the actual severity of the injury.

Near drowning has been brought up, but it is worth mentioning that even without CPR, there is a window where you can experience hallucinogenic effects, get out of the water, and still cough up the water on your own without any intervention. Strangulation is similar, there are many cases of people being strangled until they suffer minor hallucinations, pass out, and survive just fine because the assailant let up once they stopped moving.

Most seizures, strokes, and heart attacks are not fatal, with or without medical intervention.  Once the problems passes, your body just returns to normal (or at least working) function on its own.  Due to the stress these events can have on your brain, hallucinations are possible with any of them.

Comment: You make a good point about head injuries and coma. That could result in something similar, although I guess it's hard to know for sure as it's not exactly something we test for. Shock is also an interesting angle. I'm not sure a cut on the finger would really suffice, even if some proportion of the population would disagree. As for seizures, strokes and heart attacks, I'm no expert but I think they result in reconsideration of ones own life, but AFAIK not really near-death experiences. They could be a "contributory factor" though, I guess.

Comment: @RalphBolton It might depend on your definition of Near Death Experience.  I answered based on the hallucination like events reported during trauma that can make a person report that they encountered an angel, the afterlife, dead relative, etc.   If you mean a near encounter with death that just makes someone reconsider thier life, then no physical trauma is even required.  Narrowly escaping a lion could be enough to make someone reconsider thier life.

Answer (score 0):

Choking on a piece of food, losing consciousness but having the food knocked out of your gullet just in time.

Drowning in a lake, but someone pulls you out, hangs you upside down, and the water falls out of your lungs -- just in time.

Chemicals. Ate bad food or the wrong mushrooms. Almost but not quite died from poison.

Drugs. Took some sort of drug (but not too much) and almost-but-not quite died of overdose.

The first two require intervention. The interventions were certainly available at every point in history, but might not be known. They can always happen by accident. The second two require no intervention. They just require the correct amount of drugs or poison.

Comment: Drugs are actually a sort-of-obvious-when-you-think-about-it angle. A few cultures use various drugs to induce "states" for various purposes, so it's possible such a state might be near-death. It's a valid answer for sure, but my personal preference is to keep away from drugs here.

Comment: @RalphBolton You can get the same effects with poison instead of drugs, if that is more to your liking. The only difference is the dosage and intention.

Comment: @Daron the difference between a drug and a poison usually comes down to intent. If you forcefully medicated someone with alcohol, and they learned the effects, they would doubtless see this as a poisoning.

Comment: @Marvalice "dosage and intention"

Answer (score 0):

The first step in CPR, is to vigorously shake the person. This is because sometimes that's all you need. It's not often, and it's usually to make sure that the person does in fact need cpr,
but it does actually work sometimes.

Comment: It's easy to imagine a (supposedly) dead person being shaken by a friend ("wake up, wake up!"). It's possible the condition was serious enough and this was enough treatment of it to make the person experience near-death and recover.